# How to label equation without item text?

Tags: equations, itemize, labels

The enumerate environment I use is as follows:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label={\bfseries{Problem }\arabic*}]
\item\mbox{}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item The text of the problem
\begin{eqnarray}
f(0)&=&0\enspace,\nonumber\\
f(n+1)&=&f(n)+1\label{eq_label}
\end{eqnarray} 
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

I hope the equation number for f(n+1)=f(n)+1 is displayed as the normal (1). But the actual label displayed is

> (**Problem 1**.1)

So, what should I do for the equation f(n+1)=f(n)+1 to have a normal label (1) instead of above, i.e., to remove the item text (as well as its format) in the label? Of course, I also hope the subsequent citation ~\eqref{eq_label} can also display (1) as expected. Thank you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  If I create a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) using the code fragment you provided so far, I end up with the following output, which does not contain "(Problem 1.1)". Therefore, please create a MWE that allows others to reproduce the output you get.

Comment: Unrelated, never use eqnarray it is broken in many ways. Secondly please always post full minimal examples, that makes it easier to test your code.

Comment: Since you used `eqnarray`, you might want to take a look as [eqnarray vs align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/134144)  and at this article that summarizes, why to [avoid `eqnarray`](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb33-1/tb103madsen.pdf)

Comment: It's hard to understand what your trying to do with the numbering, and what you're getting.  Possibly related: `\bfseries` doesn't take an argument, so it should be `{\bfseries Problem}`, or `\textbf{Problem}`.

Comment: by default the equation number would _not_ be affected by the list numbering. As you have not provided an example we can not see how that is happening in your case. It is possible (but unusual) to declare the equation  counter is counted within enumerate. But unless you show where you hav edone that it is hard to tell you what to remove.